# Why does this Swift code for drag and drop work fine on iOS but not macOS?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to implement drag and drop into an app, so I did a small test project just to get an idea how it could work. I followed [this tutorial](https://swiftontap.com/dropdelegate) which works perfectly fine on the iOS simulator, however it does not work at all on macOS and I don't get why.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var backgroundColor: Color = .black
    let colors: [String] = ["Yellow", "Green", "Pink"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(self.colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    Text(color)
                        .font(.title)
                        .onDrag {
                            NSItemProvider(object: color as NSString)
                        }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(backgroundColor)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .onDrop(of: ["public.text"], delegate: MyDropDelegate(color: $backgroundColor))
            }
        }

    }
}

struct MyDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    @Binding var color: Color

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        if let item = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.text"]).first {
            item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.text", options: nil) { (text, error) in
                if let data = text as? Data {
                    let inputStr = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)

                    if inputStr == "Yellow" {
                        self.color = .yellow
                    } else if inputStr == "Green" {
                        self.color = .green
                    } else if inputStr == "Pink" {
                        self.color = .pink
                    } else {
                        self.color = .gray
                    }

                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

On iOS the result is straightforward : when a color name is dragged on the rectangle, the rectangle changes color.

On macOS, it seems `item` never gets filled with the content, so I get an `Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.text" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.text}` and the color doesn't change.

Any idea what could cause this (or is it intended behaviour on macOS) ?

Comment: So far SwiftUI has worked better on iOS than on macOS so that could be a reason. There is a session from wwdc this year that demonstrates drag/drop on Mac using SwiftUI, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10289/ that might be worth watching